# Image in Pygame is Dragging Pixels across screen

Tags: python, image, pygame

I have been trying to create a moving background in pygame(controlled by arrow keys). My Problem is that when an image passes the border of the windows it creates a dragging effect. All the end pixels are spread across the rest of the window.

[this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3coWr.png)

This is my movement:

```
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        if activate == True:
            x-=1
        left = False
        right = True
        bgx-=1
        bg2x-=1
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        if activate == True:
            x+=1
        left = True
        right = False
        bgx+=1
        bg2x+=1
```

This is if the images reach the end of the window:

```
    if bgx >= 1000 and right == True:
        bgx = bg2x-1000
    if bg2x >=1000 and right ==True:
        bg2x = bgx-1000
    if bgx <= -1000 and left == True:
        bgx = bg2x+1000
    if bg2x <=-1000 and left ==True:
        bg2x = bgx+1000
    if x <=-20 and right == True:
        x = 1000
    if x>=1000 and left == True:
        x=-20
```

And this is where I blit in the images:

```
        screen.blit(bg,(bgx,bgy))
        screen.blit(bg2,(bg2x,bg2y))
```

Any help is appreciated - Thanks!

I know I'm not meant to but here is my entire code

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
import os

game = ""
def home():
    global game
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,750))
    done = False
    red= (255,0,0)
    green = (0,255,0)
    blue = (0,0,255)
    white = (255,255,255)
    yList = []
    xList = []
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    for l in range(255):
        yList.append(-100)
        xList.append(-100)
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    messenger = True
    img_rect = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("space.jpg"),(1000,750)).get_rect()
    bg = pygame.Surface((img_rect.width, img_rect.height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    bg.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
    bg.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("space.jpg"),(1000,750)), img_rect)
    img_rect = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("space.jpg"),(1000,750)).get_rect()
    bg2 = pygame.Surface((img_rect.width, img_rect.height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    bg2.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
    bg2.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("space.jpg"),(1000,750)), img_rect)
    bgx = 1000
    bgy=0
    bg2x=0
    bg2y=0
    right = True
    left = False
    activate = False
    x=500
    y=450
    scale = 100
    def messenger(msg, colour, size):
        global text
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", size)

        text = font.render(msg, True, colour)
        return(text)
    while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type    == pygame.QUIT:
                            done = True
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                activate = True
                y=450
                x=500
            if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                if activate == True:
                    x-=1
                left = False
                right = True
                bgx-=1
                bg2x-=1
            if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                if activate == True:
                    x+=1
                left = True
                right = False
                bgx+=1
                bg2x+=1
            if bgx >= 1000 and right == True:
                bgx = bg2x-1000
            if bg2x >=1000 and right ==True:
                bg2x = bgx-1000
            if bgx <= -1000 and left == True:
                bgx = bg2x+1000
            if bg2x <=-1000 and left ==True:
                bg2x = bgx+1000
            if x <=-20 and right == True:
                x = 1000
            if x>=1000 and left == True:
                x=-20
            screen.blit(bg2,(bg2x,bg2y))
            screen.blit(bg,(bgx,bgy))

            if activate == True:
                y-=0.3
                scale+=1
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(x,y,(scale*10)/100,(scale*50)/100))
            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (0,0,0), [(450,750),(550,750),(525,450),(475,450)])
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,0,0),(500,450),25)
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)
    pygame.quit()
home()
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you including a screen.fill anywhere? It sounds like the previous image isn't being cleaned up before drawing the next one, creating your dragging effect.

An example:

`screen.fill((0,0,0))`

If you put that before your blitting, it should fill the screen black (clearing the previous image), before blitting your image at its new location.

Comment: now instead of dragging a black screen is displayed

Comment: Have you made sure the fill command is above where you blit your images?